# Using standard deviation in the calculation of ratio to get the scale of values

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

In the youtube tutorial (Building makemore Part 3: Activations & Gradients, BatchNorm), standard deviation is always used to calculate ratio between two values (e.g. grad to data ratio, update to data ratio) to get the scale between those 2 values.

I understand that if a is 10 times larger than b, the std dev of a will also be 10 times larger than b. But why standard deviation is used or preferred over mean?

Here is a toy example which gives the same result for both method using mean and std dev:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,5,7,9])
b = np.array([0.1,0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9])
print("mean of a:",a.mean())
print("std dev of a:",a.std())
print("mean of b:",b.mean())
print("std dev of b:",b.std())
print("---")
print("ratio using mean:", a.mean()/b.mean())
print("ratio using std dev:",a.std()/b.std())
```

Output:
mean of a: 5.0
std dev of a: 2.8284271247461903
mean of b: 0.5
std dev of b: 0.282842712474619
ratio using mean: 10.0
ratio using std dev: 10.0